# Need to open the SMS/MMS app and have an image pre-loaded into the text input in iPhone OS

Tags: iphone, sms, camera, mms

I am trying to open the SMS/MMS app on the iPhone and have an image that is saved in the camera roll pre loaded into the text field.  Is this possible?  Here is the code I have tried:

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithString:@"sms://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000041&ext=JPG"];       
NSString *escaped = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"URL: %@", escaped);

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escaped]];
```

I received the URL from a return after I saved the image to the camera roll.  Unfortunately this doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's possible.
You can pass along a phone number and that is about it.

[Uphone URL Schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#SMS)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can compose SMS in iOS 4.0 directly from your own app, but not sure about attaching images...